# git pull error for git update-index --assume-unchanged files

Tags: php, git, github

I am facing issues when doing `git pull origin master`

I have some files which have local config settings and are different from origin
I have marked them as untracked by code-> 
    `git update-index --assume-unchanged html/index.php`

Now as long as the remote index.php file does not change I can easily do `git pull`  , but when index.php file changes and I do 
    git pull origin master
I get following error
    `branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
    d532f8d..d01836e  master     -> origin/master
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by

    merge:
    html/index.php
    Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
    Aborting`

Whenever I face this issue I have to run command
    `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [filepath/filename]`

then do git pull , and then update that config file with my changes and again run
    `git update-index --assume-unchanged html/index.php`

**I do not need to take the remote config file changes in my local**, so updating those files is not necessary
I cannot change the remote file,so **what can I do locally** that I do not face an issue for these config files being updated in remote

Comment: i am using --assume-unchanged for the same purpose, and the whole point is to be able to change it later but not track those changes, but on a pull that error happens... seems like the pull should ignore merging those files you have marked, but it doesn't.   I would love an answer to this too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using instead `--skip-worktree`:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- a file
git update-index --skip-worktree -- a file
```

See  "[Difference Between '`assume-unchanged`' and '`skip-worktree`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)" for more: `--skip-worktree` should better resist to `git pull`.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work with --skip-worktree. I get the same error.

Comment: @tudor.iliescu With which version of Git? In which OS and shell?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following process. Let Git know about the changes:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged html/index.php
```

Stash those changes:

```
git stash save "Save local conf"
```

You can now pull and then restore your local changes:

```
git stash pop
```

and you can fix the conflicts accepting your local changes.

Last thing, I'd use --skip-worktree to protect the file. Why? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree)