# How to ignore an incoming commit

Tags: visual-studio, github

**I want to have two separate versions of a file: One on github and one on my local machine.**

More specifically, how do I ignore a commit coming from the remote server. In this particular case, I modified the file on github, committed it, but I want it to not change on my local machine.

I put the readme file on .gitignore.
Changed the file on github.

Made a commit

Fetched the commit on my local machine using VS2017.
How do I "ignore" the commit. And keep the two versions separate.

Comment: That seems fundamentally opposed to the idea of distributed version control. Why do you think you want this?

Comment: This must be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve that you think this is the answer?

Comment: As I stated, I wanted to have two separate versions of a readme file: One on github and one on my local machine. How do I do this using Git commands, rather than manually? (e.g. by doing the steps outlined above, putting the file on .gitignore)

Comment: jonrsharpe: Because I want the local readme to have information specific to me, and I want the github readme to be public-facing. This seems like a common scenario even for distributed VC.

Comment: @NathanFowler My answer precisely matches the "I modified the file on github, committed it, but I want it to not change on my local machine." use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least try:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- README.md
```

As [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135609/6309), that would resist a `git pull`.
And you would keep a local version of `README.md`, different from the tracked one from GitHub.
I don't presume to know if it is a good idea or not, in your particular situation.